# How do I make a Gantt Chart where the project execution phase in the WBS is modified to implement Scrum?

Tags: scrum, agile, gantt, work-breakdown-structure

How do I expand the tasks in the project execution phase in order to include enough sub-tasks that show the use of Scrum?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! A Gantt chart has nothing to do with the Scrum framework, although Scrum teams can sometimes make use of them. Please improve your question by providing additional context, including *why* you're trying to do whatever it is in a Gantt chart. As it stands, your question is unclear, and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you attempting to produce a Gantt chart?

I suggest that you read the Scrum Guide as this will provide a background into relevant Scrum artifacts.

I expect the real reason is that the business is not buying into Scrum and is expecting artifacts based on project management methodologies such as Prince or PMP in which case you have 3 options...

- Attempt to facilitate change in upper management's ideas
- Forget Scrum and use said PM methodology
- Leave and find a position willing to adopt Scrum and not saying 'Our version of Scrum'

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to like this; the answer is you cannot.

A Scrum project can ally to a release plan but a Gantt chart is the antithesis of Scrum.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes projects require more than Scrum artifacts - Scrum artifacts deal with what's in the Sprint (and product backlog) but on larger projects there are also other things to do (that fall outside of any Sprint).  In those cases, there is nothing wrong with a WBS or a schedule.  Assuming you have something like major features or epics I would show these in the WBS - the WBS should show at summary level everything that is to be delivered and ultimately any project would benefit from a clear view of all the deliverables (software or otherwise).

Sometimes there is more to life than software. :)